# Cannot retrieve data from smartcontract during tests

Tags: truffle, storage, truffle-contract, truffle-test, memory

I am writing truffle tests for my smart contract solidity version 0.4.24. The tests are emitting events to write data to memory through smart contract. But I am unable to retrieve data from functions.

Here's my smart contract functions:

> previousFarmId = 0;

```
struct Location {
        string latitude;
        string longitude;
        string locationAddress;
    }

    struct Farm {
        uint farmId;
        string farmName;
        Location location;
    }

mapping (uint => Farm) farms;

function registerFarm(string _farmName, string _farmLatitude, string _farmLongitude, string _locationAddress) public {

        previousFarmId = previousFarmId + 1;

        Location memory newLocation = farmLocation[previousFarmId];
        newLocation.latitude = _farmLatitude;
        newLocation.longitude = _farmLongitude;
        newLocation.locationAddress = _locationAddress;

        Farm memory newFarm = farms[previousFarmId];
        newFarm.farmId = previousFarmId;
        newFarm.farmName = _farmName;
        newFarm.location = newLocation;

        emit FarmRegistered(previousFarmId);

    }

    function getFarmInfo(uint _farmId) public view 
    returns (uint farmId, string farmName, string latitude, string longitude, string locationAddress) {
        Farm memory returnFarm = farms[_farmId];
        farmId = returnFarm.farmId;
        farmName = returnFarm.farmName;
        latitude = returnFarm.location.latitude;
        longitude = returnFarm.location.longitude;
        locationAddress = returnFarm.location.locationAddress;
    }
```

Here is the truffle test:

> const farmID = 1;

```
it("Testing smart contract function harvestGrapes() that allows producer to harvest grapes", async() => {

        const supplyChain = await SupplyChain.deployed();

        await supplyChain.addProducer(producerID, {from: deployerID});

        await supplyChain.registerFarm(farmName, farmLatitude, farmLongitude, farmAddress, {from: producerID});

        const resultFarms = await supplyChain.getFarmInfo.call(farmID);

        console.log('Farm ID: ' + resultFarms[0]);
        console.log('Farm Name: ' + resultFarms[1]);
        console.log('Farm Latitude: ' + resultFarms[2]);
        console.log('Farm Longitude: ' + resultFarms[3]);
        console.log('Farm Address: ' + resultFarms[4]); 
}
```

> Console Logs:

```
Farm ID: 0
Farm Name:
Farm Latitude:
Farm Longitude:
Farm Address:
```

> Events emitted during test:

```
   ProducerAdded(account: <indexed>)
    FarmRegistered(farmId: 1)
    GrapesHarvested(grapesId: 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part doesn't do what you want.

```
function registerFarm(string _farmName, string _farmLatitude, string _farmLongitude, string _locationAddress) public {

        previousFarmId = previousFarmId + 1;

        Location memory newLocation = farmLocation[previousFarmId];
        newLocation.latitude = _farmLatitude;
        newLocation.longitude = _farmLongitude;
        newLocation.locationAddress = _locationAddress;

        Farm memory newFarm = farms[previousFarmId];
        newFarm.farmId = previousFarmId;
        newFarm.farmName = _farmName;
        newFarm.location = newLocation;

        emit FarmRegistered(previousFarmId);

    }
```

First you assign function arguments to the `memory` variable `newLocation`. Then, you assign the arguments to another `memory` variable `newFarm`. They're both `memory`, so they won't persist.

Consider:

```
function registerFarm(string _farmName, string _farmLatitude, string _farmLongitude, string _locationAddress) public {

        previousFarmId = previousFarmId + 1;

        Location storage newLocation = farmLocation[previousFarmId];
        newLocation.latitude = _farmLatitude;
        newLocation.longitude = _farmLongitude;
        newLocation.locationAddress = _locationAddress;

        emit FarmRegistered(previousFarmId);

    }
```

`newLocation` is a storage pointer, so assignments to it go directly to storage. Storage will persist after the function finishes executing. `memory` variables are extinguished when their function or in-function scope (new compiler further narrows scopes) finishes.

You might find Remix is handy for superficial and manual testing before moving on to unit tests.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad it helped. More on `storage` pointers over here: https://blog.b9lab.com/storage-pointers-in-solidity-7dcfaa536089